# Is f(A) Lebesgue measurable when A is lebesgue measurable and f is a function of the class C1?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let A be a Lebesgue measurable set. Let f: $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a
 function of the class $C^1$;

Is this true that f(A) is lebesgue measurable?

I know that this is true when f is injective.

But I don't know that  when f is not injective.

Could you teach me it is true or not?

Sorry for my poor English.

Comment: To elaborate on my comment: You can express every measurable set as $A =\bigcup K_n \cup N$ with compact sets $K_n$ and a null-set $N$. Then, $f(A)=\bigcup f(K_n) \cup f(N)$ is measurable if $f$ maps nullsets to nullsets, since images of compact sets are compact (because $f$ is continuous).

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. But still I can't understand. are $K_n$ a compact sets? I think $K_n$ are  just closed sets,  not always compact (i.e. not always bounded). I can understand your answer except this part.

Comment: If you find closed sets $K_n$ satisfying the desired equation, use $K_{n,k}=K_n \cap [-k,k]$. These will be countably many compact sets, which still satisfy the desired identity.

Comment: Oh, That's true! Thank you very much! I understood. I greatly appreciate your answer!